# environment system variables: path not recognized error

Tags: java, android, sdk

I need set system environment path for java, sdk, opencv, ndk etc..
can I put all the path under the same variable "path", & use the semicoma, ";" to separate each other.

The problem is when I try to test by using cmd.exe
It can only recognize the first path values.

Example: when I put sdk's path on first place and follow by java's path, it shown
[image: sdk path; java path;]

vice verse, it shown

[image: jav path; sdk path]

SO I should separate the path by difference variables name? WHat is the best way to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the output from `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: it shown out all the path values that I set. sdk, java, ndk... etc..

Comment: Please paste the output here so we can take a look at it ...

Comment: C:\android-ndk-r10; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin; C:\andorid-sdk\sdk\tools; C:\opencv\build;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin;  C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; ; C:\andorid-sdk\sdk\tools; C:\opencv\build;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space after each `;` character when you set the path.

You also somehow have eveything in the path **twice**. See [How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) for the correct way to set the path.

You path should look like:

```
C:\android-ndk-r10;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;C:\andorid-sdk\sdk\tools; C:\opencv\build;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind‌​owsPowerShell\v1.0\;
```

Comment: It's work!! Thank you so much!!
Thanks for share the link too. ^^

Comment: But why everything in the path twice? It it because I set the same values in user variable? Actually I quite confuse on where should I set the path. Is under user or system variables?